# How to get selected fields from sp_spaceused query in mssql

Tags: sql-server

For My query

> exec sp_spaceused 'tablbename'

It returns

name | rows | reserved | data | index size | unused

But, I need only **reserved** field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, but I hope there is a better way

```
DECLARE @spaceUsed TABLE (
    name varchar(255), 
    rows int, 
    reserved varchar(50), 
    data varchar(50), 
    index_size varchar(50), 
    unused varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @spaceUsed
exec sp_spaceused 'YOUR_TABLE'

SELECT reserved FROM @spaceUsed
```